# Get comment or likes count for YouTube video using API 3.0

Tags: c#, .net, google-api, youtube-api

I want to get number of comments and/or likes for video with specific YouTube ID.
I am using YouTube API v3.0.

I was searching through API documentation and can't find appropriate method.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After having better look at Google API documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list), I have found that I can use "statistics" part parameter of Videos.List API in order to get what I want.

Exact HTTP post request should be (notice **part=statistics** parameter):

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=statistics&id=sTPtBvcYkO8&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

And response is:

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#videoListResponse",
 "etag": "\"kjEFmP90GvrCl8BObMQtGoRfgaQ/XN5YXMZGQaruwTWTekZu7fQthdY\"",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 1,
  "resultsPerPage": 1
 },
 "items": [
  {

   "kind": "youtube#video",
   "etag": "\"kjEFmP90GvrCl8BObMQtGoRfgaQ/QbzZs_aBNpzkZJxTVM7YgQeEY3g\"",
   "id": "sTPtBvcYkO8",
   "statistics": {
    "viewCount": "3215321",
    "likeCount": "17003",
    "dislikeCount": "263",
    "favoriteCount": "0",
    "commentCount": "621"
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

Comment: It is not return likeCount  ?

Answer (score 8):

If you want number of comments and/or likes for video with specific YouTube ID, you need to use the YouTube API V3 with `youtube.videos.list`

with the parameters :

```
part=id, statistics
id=VIDEO_ID
```

This is the output :

```
 "items": [
  {

   "kind": "youtube#video",
   "etag": "\"kjEFmP90GvrCl8BObMQtGoRfgaQ/-hharrXKffaZ3z4sIleW9K-Nf2Q\"",
   "id": "_RtGuUAQOC4",
   "statistics": {
    "viewCount": "484851",
    "likeCount": "3993",
    "dislikeCount": "72",
    "favoriteCount": "0",
    "commentCount": "262"
   }
  }
 ]
```

**[LIVE DEMO](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.videos.list?part=id%252C%20%20statistics&id=_RtGuUAQOC4&_h=2&)**

You can find all informations about video list in the doc :https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list?hl=fr :