# Find how many likes does a video get on Youtube with Google Api in .Net

Tags: c#, .net, google-api

I am studying google api and .Net 
I did some studies and I wrote a code, but I don't know how can I find the number of likes of a youtube video using Google api in .Net ?

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to the LINK : 
[Get comment or likes count for YouTube video using API 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25826571/get-comment-or-likes-count-for-youtube-video-using-api-3-0)
or you can use `HttpWebRequest` to Download the full content of the video page then you can get the count of likes/comments By `spliting Strings`