# C# - YouTube API v3, Get likes count

Tags: c#, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm trying to get likes count using Google API v3 in C#.

```
SearchResource.ListRequest listRequest = service.Search.List("snippet");
listRequest.Q = args;
listRequest.MaxResults = 5;
IList<SearchResult> searchListResponse = (await listRequest.ExecuteAsync()).Items;
```

But that only give me generic information (like video ID, snippet, etc...)

I found some similar questions like this one
[Get comment or likes count for YouTube video using API 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25826571/get-comment-or-likes-count-for-youtube-video-using-api-3-0)
But they only tell how to do it using HTTP request and not using the .NET library

I tried adding the statistic keyword in the Search.List thing like that

```
service.Search.List("snippet,statistics");
```

But it return me a 400 error

```
Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
snippet statistics [400]
Errors [
    Message[snippet statistics] Location[part - parameter] 
    Reason[unknownPart] Domain[youtube.part]
]
```

So my question is how do I get likes count using Google API v3 in C# ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with .NET but I can tell you the likeCount is in statistics but that is not available through the Search endpoint. You must use the [Videos](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) endpoint and request statistics that way. Hopefully that will point you in the right direction.